# NativeCSS & Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, css, xamarin, xamarin.android, nativecss

I need some help getting NativeCSS running for Xamarin.Android (in Xamarin Studio).
What I have done:

-Added .dll to References in my Xamarin project.

-Added styles.css file to different folders (root, Assets, Resources, and also to the debug output folder). (Question: What is the folder, NativeCSS expects the .css file??)

-Added the following code to my MainActivity.cs:

```
        NativeCSS.StyleWithCSS("styles.css",
            new Uri("http:url"), 
            RemoteContentRefreshPeriod.Never);
```

But I can not see any style changes of my project.

I hope  somebody can help me.
I really appreciate every help.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the sample project TaskyDroid, which does exactly what you want:

[image: Assets folder]
[image: Asset Properties]
[image: Code]